# inset into exec dbo.sp_executesql (multiple statement string)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-insert, sp-executesql

I use this code:

```
select @SQLString=N'select ....(long select query).....'
    + char(10)  + '; drop table _item_list '
```

and afterwards

```
insert @tbl EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @SQLString
```

It seems to be working, but can someone give me some clear info on this? I was expecting the executesql thing to have to be "faithful", as in related in its entirety, to the insert statement preceding it. It seems however that it has no problem feeding the select to the insert, and doing the drop table independently. Also, is the ; before the drop necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to populate data to a table:

1. `INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES`
2. `SELECT INTO FROM`
3. `INSERT INTO SELECT`
4. `INSERT INTO EXEC`  <-- what you are talking about

And the `;` is not very necessary, just to separate batch, the result will be the same, but for some may need to consider scope, such as batch or session, then it matters.

**UPDATE:**
That is fine with `irrelevant statements` afterward of the `select`, even there are more than one `select` in your USP, but you have to make sure all the returned results (the `select` statement) need to be compatible with the table definition that you are referring to.

Comment: So let me state the question in a more clear way: in case of the insert into exec, as long as the FIRST statement of the exec is a select or values statement, then the exec string may have any number of irrelevant statements afterward?